# select where column contains exact string

Tags: php, mysql

table `arts` column `tags` - example:

`sky, code, earth, codepen`

```
$tag = 'code';    
$sql = "select * from arts where tags like ('%" . $tag . "%')";
```

Result - `code, codepen`

I need only `code` in result, i.e somethin like this:

```
$sql = "select * from arts where tags contains only (' . $tag . ')";
```

Any help?

Comment: AND that's why NORMALIZATION is important. Yo have to save each one separately as single-record. everything will become fine and easy. Otherwise you have to face more bigger issues in future

Comment: [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), however really fixed your [list of doom](http://gtowey.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-fix-comma-separated-list-of-doom.html) before you incur more software debt.

Comment: @AlivetoDie, what about Manoj's answer?

Comment: @qadenza  as i said you will face more problem in case of  liver search, add ,edit,delete etc..... May be the solution will work for you but again i will stay at the same thing called NORMALIZATION.

Comment: @qadenza - That might solve _one_ issue, but having them comma separated like that will still give you more problems. Normalization is the way to go. It might seem like extra work now, but believe me, it's going to be worth it in the long run.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, could you give me an example of a problem using `find_in_set`, pls?

Comment: First off, I have never even mentioned `find_in_set`. I said: _"comma separated like that will still give you more problems"_ and that `find_in_set` might solve _one_ problem (your current one). But there are other issues with storing multiple values in the same column. Ex. the DB won't be able to use indexes as efficiently on that column. How would you perform a join? If you want to delete one tag, you need to select the complete column, split it up on comma, remove the tag, implode it again and update the column. In a normalized  DB, you just need to delete a record and you're done.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson,  I see but the price of normalization is - a seaparate row for each tag!. I could have 20 tags for an article, and so must have 20 identical rows with just specific one tag? I would call this `de-normalization`.

Comment: Please read up on the subject a bit before arguing against it. https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/. It might seem like extra work in the beginning, but in the end, it will make things _much_ easier. There's a reason that's the norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FIND_IN_SET to check values in a CSV column.

```
$sql = "select * from arts where FIND_IN_SET('" . $tag . "', tags)";
```